# Nested chain vs duplicated information

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

There is a models.py with 4 model.
Its standard record is:

```
class Main(models.Model):
    stuff            = models.IntegerField()
class Second(models.Model):
    nested           = models.ForeignKey(Main)
    stuff            = models.IntegerField()
class Third(models.Model):
    nested           = models.ForeignKey(Second)
    stuff            = models.IntegerField()
class Last(models.Model):
    nested           = models.ForeignKey(Third)
    stuff            = models.IntegerField()
```

and there is another variant of Last model:

```
class Last(models.Model):
    nested1          = models.ForeignKey(Main)
    nested2          = models.ForeignKey(Second)
    nested           = models.ForeignKey(Third)
    stuff            = models.IntegerField()
```

Will that way save some database load?

The information in nested1 and nested2 will duplicate fields in Secod and Third and even it may become outdated ( fortunately not in my case, as the data will not be changed, only new is added ). 
But from my thoughts it may save database load, when I'm looking all Last records for a certain Main record. Or when I'm looking only for Main.id for specific Last item.

Am I right?

Will it really save the load or there is a better practice?

Comment: What are the purposes of your models? Sometimes it would be impractical to directly connect two models when in reality they are only connected through others. I understand your question is about database load, but often there is one option that just makes more sense logically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends how you access the data. By default Django will make another call to the database when you access a foreign key. So if you want to make less calls to the database, you can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to prefetch the models in foreign keys.